# How to declare scope element inside of config?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

*sorry my bad english*

My problem is How can I declare scope inside of `.config` when I eter `scope` inside of config like this `app.config(['$scope', function($scope){//...}]);` It throws the following error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Did my suggestion help you at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only inject providers curing configuration. Alternatively, you can accomplish something similar on `.run()`. Note that you can only inject `$rootScope`, but all `$scope`'s will inherit whatever value you are trying to assign

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    // assign your values here
});
```